# diff files with the same names

Tags: unix, diff

In one directory I have about 20 files (let's say they are named from `1` to `20`) and in the second one I have 200 files (named from `1` to `200`). How could I `diff` only the ones with the same names?

Can this be done with a oneliner without using bash scripts?

Comment: There is this option: `--unidirectional-new-file` ---> `treat absent first files as empty`. It seems to work.

Comment: @fedorqui so simple. I didn't really understand `man` for this command, but it works, so I'll accept your answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From `man diff`:

```
   --unidirectional-new-file
          treat absent first files as empty
```

#### Test

Given this structure:

```
seq 5 > aaa/a1
seq 5 > aaa/a2
seq 5 > aaa/a3
seq 5 > bbb/a1
seq 10 > bbb/a3
```

That is:

```
$ tree aaa
aaa
├── a1
├── a2
└── a3

0 directories, 3 files
$ tree bbb
bbb
├── a1
└── a3

0 directories, 2 files
```

Let's compare them:

```
$ diff aaa bbb --unidirectional-new-file
diff --unidirectional-new-file aaa/a1 bbb/a1
5a6,10
> 6
> 7
> 8
> 9
> 10
Only in aaa: a2
```

Let's compare the other way round:

```
$ diff bbb aaa --unidirectional-new-file
diff --unidirectional-new-file bbb/a1 aaa/a1
6,10d5
< 6
< 7
< 8
< 9
< 10
diff --unidirectional-new-file bbb/a2 aaa/a2
0a1,5
> 1
> 2
> 3
> 4
> 5
```

So the order matters: it mentions files that exist in the first directory, but not in the second one.